# Android RAM overused

Tags: android, memory

I ran into a problem that drives me crazy SO:

Here is my implementation of a ViewPager(I know it's horrible) which does the parallax effect (Moving background) and it works just fine.

```
package com.breadwallet.tools.adapter;

/**
 * Created by Mihail on 6/29/15.
 */

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;

import com.breadwallet.presenter.activities.MainActivity;
import com.breadwallet.tools.animation.FragmentAnimator;
import com.breadwallet.tools.animation.SpringAnimator;


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class ParallaxViewPager extends ViewPager {


    public static final int FIT_WIDTH = 0;
    public static final int FIT_HEIGHT = 1;
    public static final float OVERLAP_FULL = 1f;
    public static final float OVERLAP_HALF = 0.5f;
    public static final float OVERLAP_QUARTER = 0.25f;
    private static final float CORRECTION_PERCENTAGE = 0.01f;
    public Bitmap bitmap;
    private Rect source, destination;
    private int scaleType;
    private int chunkWidth;
    private int projectedWidth;
    private float overlap;
    private OnPageChangeListener secondOnPageChangeListener;
    private MainActivity app;


    public ParallaxViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
        app = MainActivity.getApp();
    }


    public ParallaxViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
        app = MainActivity.getApp();
    }


    private void init() {
        source = new Rect();
        destination = new Rect();
        scaleType = FIT_HEIGHT;
        overlap = OVERLAP_HALF;


        setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    source.left = (int) Math.floor((position + positionOffset - CORRECTION_PERCENTAGE) * chunkWidth);
                    source.right = (int) Math.ceil((position + positionOffset + CORRECTION_PERCENTAGE) * chunkWidth + projectedWidth);
                    destination.left = (int) Math.floor((position + positionOffset - CORRECTION_PERCENTAGE) * getWidth());
                    destination.right = (int) Math.ceil((position + positionOffset + 1 + CORRECTION_PERCENTAGE) * getWidth());
                    invalidate();
                }

                if (secondOnPageChangeListener != null) {
                    secondOnPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (secondOnPageChangeListener != null) {
                    secondOnPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
                }
                app.setPagerIndicator(position);
                if (FragmentAnimator.level == 0) {
                    if (position == 1) {
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                SpringAnimator.showBouncySlide(getRootView(), SpringAnimator.TO_RIGHT);
                            }
                        }, 80);
                    } else if (position == 0) {
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                SpringAnimator.showBouncySlide(getRootView(), SpringAnimator.TO_LEFT);
                            }
                        }, 80);
                    }
                }

                Log.e("AdapterParalax", "Showing animation!!!!!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                if (secondOnPageChangeListener != null) {
                    secondOnPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        destination.top = 0;
        destination.bottom = h;
        if (getAdapter() != null && bitmap != null)
            calculateParallaxParameters();
    }

    private void calculateParallaxParameters() {
        if (bitmap.getWidth() < getWidth() && bitmap.getWidth() < bitmap.getHeight() && scaleType == FIT_HEIGHT) {
            Log.w(ParallaxViewPager.class.getName(), "Invalid bitmap bounds for the current device, parallax effect will not work.");
        }


        final float ratio = (float) getHeight() / bitmap.getHeight();
        if (ratio != 1) {
            switch (scaleType) {
                case FIT_WIDTH:
                    source.top = (int) ((bitmap.getHeight() - bitmap.getHeight() / ratio) / 2);
                    source.bottom = bitmap.getHeight() - source.top;
                    chunkWidth = (int) Math.ceil((float) bitmap.getWidth() / (float) getAdapter().getCount());
                    projectedWidth = chunkWidth;
                    break;
                case FIT_HEIGHT:
                default:
                    source.top = 0;
                    source.bottom = bitmap.getHeight();
                    projectedWidth = (int) Math.ceil(getWidth() / ratio);
                    chunkWidth = (int) Math.ceil((bitmap.getWidth() - projectedWidth) / (float) getAdapter().getCount() * overlap);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Sets the background from a resource file.
     *
     * @param resid
     */
    @Override
    public void setBackgroundResource(int resid) {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resid);
    }


    /**
     * Sets the background from a Drawable.
     *
     * @param background
     */
    @Override
    public void setBackground(Drawable background) {
        bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) background).getBitmap();
    }


    /**
     * Deprecated.
     * Sets the background from a Drawable.
     *
     * @param background
     */
    @Override
    public void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background) {
        bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) background).getBitmap();
    }


    /**
     * Sets the background from a bitmap.
     *
     * @param bitmap
     * @return The ParallaxViewPager object itself.
     */
    public ParallaxViewPager setBackground(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
        return this;
    }


    /**
     * Sets how the view should scale the background. The available choices are:
     * <ul>
     * <li>FIT_HEIGHT - the height of the image is resized to matched the height of the View, also stretching the width to keep the aspect ratio. The non-visible part of the bitmap is divided into equal parts, each of them sliding in at the proper position.</li>
     * <li>FIT_WIDTH - the width of the background image is divided into equal chunks, each taking up the whole width of the screen.</li>
     * </ul>
     *
     * @param scaleType
     * @return
     */
    public ParallaxViewPager setScaleType(final int scaleType) {
        if (scaleType != FIT_WIDTH && scaleType != FIT_HEIGHT)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal argument: scaleType must be FIT_WIDTH or FIT_HEIGHT");
        this.scaleType = scaleType;
        return this;
    }


    /**
     * Sets the amount of overlapping with the setOverlapPercentage(final float percentage) method. This is a number between 0 and 1, the smaller it is, the slower is the background scrolling.
     *
     * @param percentage
     * @return The ParallaxViewPager object itself.
     */
    public ParallaxViewPager setOverlapPercentage(final float percentage) {
        if (percentage <= 0 || percentage >= 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal argument: percentage must be between 0 and 1");
        overlap = percentage;
        return this;
    }


    /**
     * Recalculates the parameters of the parallax effect, useful after changes in runtime.
     *
     * @return The ParallaxViewPager object itself.
     */
    public ParallaxViewPager invalidateParallaxParameters() {
        calculateParallaxParameters();
        return this;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (bitmap != null)
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, source, destination, null);
    }

    public void addOnPageChangeListener(OnPageChangeListener listener) {
        secondOnPageChangeListener = listener;
    }
}
```

so the problem is that this guy eats up to 40mb of RAM which gave me an OutOfMemoryError which is fine because I could simple add some more memory to the app but why does it eat so much memory? is that normal? can I do anything about it or this is just a normal behavior in Android? because iOS does not eat so much memory in general. The image that I use for the background weights only 27kb. So I am more interested in some expert opinion on what did I miss or don't know. Thanks fellas.

Comment: what is the size of your bitmap? Width x Height

Comment: Did you fixed it? In that case, can you post your solution?

Comment: Not yet, I feel like the next response is the solution but I've been on a vacation so I'll check it tonight.

Comment: Can you please stare the size in pixel of your bitmap?

Comment: Oh yes I'm sorry, 810 x 810

Comment: What Android version are you using?

Comment: target is 22, min 19, the phone that I test is KitKat 19

Comment: @MimmoGrottoli Sorry I totally messed up, 2880 x 3408 I checked the other bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the bitmap you are using is too wide. It takes width x height x 4 bytes of ram. You should resize your bitmap to fit the screen, if it's not enough you should considering to reduce the number of bits x pixel (by default it's 32)

Answer (score 1):

What I see is you used onPageScrolled which calls again and again as you perform scrolling this also tends to perform subsequent dependent operations again and again and results to ram consumption.

Try to use some listener or localbroadcast.